# Scene where character kisses another character in order to trick him and steal from him

Tags: story-identification, movie, books, tv, episode-identification

I have a vague memory of a scene and I want to know what it's from. I can't say if this is from a book/movie/show, or even if it belongs in this stack exchange category, but let me explain it as well as I can and maybe someone here will know what I'm talking about.

What I remember is this: There was a character who I believe was female, and I believe she was being held hostage(?) by a male character, who was the antagonist. I believe the male character was interested in her romantically, and she (as the "good guy") was obviously repulsed by him and avoiding his advances.

But she needs to get something from him, in order to escape, perhaps? Maybe keys, or a weapon? Something he has on his person. So she pretends that she's interested in him, and tricks him into kissing her and while they're kissing she attempts to grab this thing from him, but just before she succeeds, he realizes what she's doing and backs away. And he's very upset to realize she wasn't being sincere and was just trying to escape.

I probably have some details wrong, but hopefully someone can figure out what I'm talking about!

Quick note: There's a similar situation to this in the book Shatter Me. The scene from that book is what triggered the memory, but that's not the answer.

Edit: I think it was probably a scene from 3x18 of Once Upon a Time, although in that case I had the genders wrong. I was also imagining something from longer ago in my past, whereas I would've watched this only three or four years ago. But this is the most likely answer. Thank you to commenters for helping!

Comment: Game of Thrones has a couple of scenes like that with Osha trying it and succeeding with Theon and failing with Ramsay.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about sci-fi or Fantasy, and unfortunately is off-topic here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is too vague.  It seems like the sort of thing that has probably happened in lots of movies and TV shows (and books, I'm sure) over the years.  Barring any more specific details that might narrow it down, I doubt anyone here would be able to help you, short of listing every instance they can think of (list questions are generally discouraged.)

Comment: @Edlothiad what if it's from fantasy or sci-fi? You never know. I do understand though. I'm brand new to stack exchange, do you know where it might be on-topic?

Comment: Pirates of the Caribbean has a scene where Elizabeth kisses Jack Sparrow and handcuffs him to the mast when they are abandoning ship to escape the Kraken. Does that sound like what you are looking for?

Comment: Good suggestions but it's not GoT or PotC

Comment: @Steve-O if only I had something more specific to add! It's unfortunate because it's really been bugging me.

Comment: Do you remember ethnicity of the characters? Age range? Was he ugly or handsome? Was she stealing keys, a keycard, a magic wand?

Comment: TVTropes Entry: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KissOfDistraction

Comment: @FuzzyBoots that link is super helpful!! Thank you. I also didn't realize how many similar situations there are to this! Anyway, I might have found it, I'm gonna have to rewatch the scene to be sure but I think I was thinking of Once Upon a Time. Though if that's the case I had the genders wrong.

Comment: @JennyJen, we normally re-open questions if they've got an on-topic answer. Do you remember if it was from a SFF work?

Comment: @Edlothiad I think it was probably from Once Upon a Time (even though I definitely had some details wrong) so that is fantasy. :) Anyway, I care more about the answer than the status of this question, so if it would be better to close it or delete it, that's fine.

Comment: I would say just put "possibly once upon a time" and it'll stay open.

Comment: The problem with this question is its uncertainty.  You have no idea if it was a book or movie, sf&f or other.  So, you can't really select a group of people, on SE or elsewhere, who'd be expected to recognize it more readily.  My recommendation is that you let it stew it the back of your mind, and wait for that fortuitous epiphany or revelation which strikes your recollection perfectly.